# char initialization in struct

Tags: c, struct, char

I have the code below. I get the "warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]" warning when I build it.

```
struct routing {
    int hop_distance;
    char timeinfo[13];
    char sender_ID[16];
    char gateway[16];
};

struct routing user_list[40]  =  { [0]={0,0,0,0}};
```

I guess I get the warning because of the char initialization, how should I initialize it?

```
struct routing user_list[40]  =  { [0]={0,{0},{0},{0}}};
```

or

```
struct routing user_list[40]  =  { [0]={0,'\0','\0','\0'}};
```

or some other way?

Comment: memset(&user_list, 0, 40 * sizeof(routing));

Comment: Note the same is achieved shorter with `struct routing user_list[40] = {{0}};`. Any fields and array elements without an explicit initialiser then are initialised as static objects would be, to the appropriate 0-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing element 0 of your array. Therefore:

```
 struct routing user_list[40] = { [0]={...} };
```

So far you got it right. In this element, you are initializing four members:

```
 struct routing user_list[40] = { [0]={..., ..., ..., ...} };
```

Also good.

Element 1 is an `int`, so you can initialize it with a number, such as 0.

Elements 2, 3 and 4 are arrays of `char`, so you can initialize them the same way you initialize arrays of `char`. `{0}`, `{'\0'}` or `""` they all work:

```
 struct routing user_list[40] = { [0]={0, {0}, {'\0'}, ""} };
```

Note the above is an example showing you can use all three methods. In reality you take one method and use it in all three.

The reason you got a warning is because you are trying to initialize the arrays with a `0`, instead of `{0}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround arrays with curly braces:

```
struct routing user_list[40] = {
    [0] = { 0, { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } }
};
```